# Split Stages by Agent for Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a declarative pipeline, I would like to:

Run Stage1-5 grouped on Executor/Agent1 (same instantiated executor)
Run Step6 on no agent (approval) (does not hold up agent during wait)
Run Step7-10 grouped on Executor/Agent2 (same instantiated executor)

Is this possible?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, what have you tried? Please include your pipeline code and error messages to help people assist with you question.

Comment: I have tried to declare an agent globally under `pipeline {}` and then override it for a specific stage (the approval stage) with `agent none` but it still holds the agent hostage so overriding does not seem to work.  Other than that I only see the option to explicitly set the agent at the stage level.

Comment: Defining agent none at the top-level of the Pipeline ensures that an Executor will not be assigned unnecessarily. Using agent none also forces each stage section contain its own agent section.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

This seems to indicate contrary to what I am trying to accomplish